# how to collect simulation data every n ticks from julia agents

Tags: julia, agent

I have an agent-based model in Julia for which I need to collect data, I am running it like:

```
ensemblerun!(models, agent_step!, dummystep, 1000; adata, parallel = true);
```

It actually reports values at every step, but I would like to collect data only every 50 steps.

Where should I introduce a condition like:

```
steps mod 50 == 0 # then proceed collecting data
```

I really have no idea where to insert any kind of condition... it seems an hardwired behaviour of the framework... but maybe I am missing the point, being new at this Julia Agents

Comment: Since I haven't tried it, but just googled, I'm leaving this as a comment, but perhaps: `ensemblerun!(models, agent_step!, dummystep, 1000; adata, parallel = true, when=((m,s)->s % 50 == 0))` to run the model will do the trick. Or, in other words, `when` parameter returns a boolean indicating when to trace with parameters being (model, step_number).

Comment: this is it! thank you, works perfectly... if you want to convert to answer I'll accept it right away..

Comment: Changed the `==0` to `==1` in the answer to make it trace the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the simulation with:

```
ensemblerun!(models, agent_step!, dummystep, 1000; 
  adata, parallel = true, when=((m,s)->s % 50 == 1))
```

More explicitly, the `when` parameter can be a function that returns a boolean indicating when to trace. The function's parameters being (model, step_number) and are self-explanatory.